# Display multiple blocks, radio is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some help in editing my current script.

I use 1 radio button, that should hide/display multiple divs when 1 of the radio buttons is selected.

It works fine for just 1 div, but I can not make it work with multiple divs.

My current HTML:

```
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group form-group-xl">
                <label for="Particulier"><input type="radio" id="Particulier"checked="checked" name="checkzakelijk" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />Particulier</label>
                <label for="Zakelijk"><input type="radio" id="Zakelijk" name="checkzakelijk" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />Bedrijf</label>
              </div>
            </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6" id="checkzakelijk1" style="display:none;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="customfield{$customfield.id}">{$customfield.name}</label>
                    <div class="control">
                        {$customfield.input} {$customfield.description}
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="checkzakelijk2" style="display:none;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="customfield{$customfield.id}">{$customfield.name}</label>
                    <div class="control">
                        {$customfield.input} {$customfield.description}
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Current script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowHideDiv() {
            var chkYes = document.getElementById("Zakelijk");
            var dvPassport = document.getElementById("checkzakelijk");
            var dvPassport = document.getElementById("checkzakelijk1");
            var dvPassport = document.getElementById("checkzakelijk2");
            dvPassport.style.display = chkYes.checked ? "block" : "none";
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: every time you declare `var dvPassport`, it receives a new value (an element in this case), so only the last line would take effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting `dvPassport` variable, so only the last element will be have its effect.

*Change it to*

```
function ShowHideDiv() {
    var chkYes = document.getElementById("Zakelijk");

    var dvPassport1 = document.getElementById("checkzakelijk");
    var dvPassport2 = document.getElementById("checkzakelijk1");
    var dvPassport3 = document.getElementById("checkzakelijk2");

    var display = chkYes.checked ? "block" : "none";

    dvPassport1.style.display = display;
    dvPassport2.style.display = display;
    dvPassport3.style.display = display;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a closer look at this bit:

```
var dvPassport = document.getElementById("checkzakelijk");
var dvPassport = document.getElementById("checkzakelijk1");
var dvPassport = document.getElementById("checkzakelijk2");
```

What you are doing here is declaring a new variable with the same name multiple times, which doesn't make much sense.

I would suggest jQuery class selector, i.e.

```
$(".col-sm-6").hide();
```

Also, in cases where you want to apply something to multiple elements, it's worth giving them the same class, rather than listing the ids. It's simpler and makes the code much more readable.